# What is causing this shading problem?

Tags: artifacts

What is causing this artefact? Normals are fine, no doubles and no interior faces to be causing this

[image][image]

[image][image]

Comment: The third illustration shows an inverted face? ... but altogether, it would be better to have quad face-loops follow the flow of  surface features, rather than the triangulation.

Comment: hello, what artefact are you talking about, you've marked sharp, is it your problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options to get rid of the artefact I think you are talking about:

## Case # 1

If you're talking about the smoothing, go to the *Object Data Properties* tab and enable *Auto Smooth*:[image]

## Case # 2

If you're mentioning the black hole in your mesh, it looks like you have a hole in your mesh there. Go to *Vertex Select Mode* in *Edit Mode* and select the vertices around the hole. Now press `F` on your keyboard to fill the face.

What I mentioned is the apparent problem, without more details or your .blend file I cannot guess more.